# Java: How to get type class object of generic method?

Tags: java, generics

** **Not a duplicate as it is specific to method and not a class** **

I am using some third party library which accepts `class` object as parameter. 
I want to get class object of **generic type method** in Java -

**Please note that my class is not generic only one of the method is generic.**

```
public class DataAccessor {
    public <T> Page<T> getPage(final Integer pageIndex) {
        // ...
        // Some processing
        // ...

        // Third-part library which accepts Class as parameter
        Object respponse = library.getPage(pageIndex, <Class object T ???>);        

        // ...
        // Some processing
        // ...
    }
}
```

How to get such class type if my class is not generic?

Comment: Because of type erasure, you have to pass the class into the method. Like, `public <T> Page<T> getPage(final Class<T> cls, final Integer pageIndex)`

Comment: There's a reason the third-party method requires a `Class` parameter, even though it's (presumably) generic. You can't get around it by wrapping the call in another method.

Comment: @shmosel It is not wrapping call... there is pre and post processing involved.

Comment: That's not really the point.